# How to assign specific value of list into specific object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am getting header_information of the my file from external source  for example like below:

```
header_information="studentname,branch,collage,place"
```

after that I am  converting the string into list of Strings.

```
headerlist=header_information.split(",")
sid=headerlist[0]
bran=headerlist[1]
coll=headerlist[2]
plc=headerlist[3]
```

as per my requirement i have to create another list with specified order.
for example:

```
list1=[coll,plc,sid,bran]
```

but some time header will come different(order) string like.

```
header_information="collage,branch,studentname,place"
but as per my above code :`sid=headerlist[0]`
it will assign `sid=coll`

but i should always assign expected output is like below   
sid="studentname"
coll="collage"
bran=="branch"
plc="place
```

please help me on this.

Comment: Can you post the problem code? Also have you considered using a dictionary instead to namespace your variables?

Comment: How will you know the difference between elements? You can't tell python if `spiky` is a dog or `place`, unless you build a sophisticated AI solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some way of differentiating each item, otherwise this task is near impossible. Do you know all the possible inputs for each header parameter? Your code has to have some way of knowing which substring is which without human knowledge of what name would be a college and what name would be a student name. For example, does every student name contain a space? Does every branch name contain the word branch? Is a student ID a number? You must find a unique attribute to each field and assign based on that, or complain to your external source and get consistent headers.

Answer (score 0):

While you didn't provide that in your question, my crystal ball has told me that you're trying to read a csv file with fields in arbitrary order, and write them back in a certain defined order.

You can use `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` for that:

```
with open('yourcsvfile.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
```

That will parse the header and give you an object that yields dicts with each header part pointing to a value - the order won't matter because you use the header name itself to refer to a value:

```
    for row in cf:
        print(row['collage'], row['place'], row['studentname'], row['branch'])
```

That will print the data in this specific order, every time, regardless of the order in the source file. Note that you don't need a separate variable for each value, because by using dicts, you keep the namespace inside the `row` variable.

You could write back to a file in a specific order of the header:

```
with open('yourcsvfile.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    with open('destination.csv', 'w') as fw:
        cw = csv.DictWriter(fw, ['collage', 'place', 'studentname', 'branch'])
        cw.writeheader()
        cw.writerows(cf)
```

This code will read a file with the header in any order, but write another file back with the specific order determined in the code.